# Batch file auto input fortran program

Tags: batch-file, cmd, fortran

I have a simple compiled Fortran program like so:

```
program main
    integer :: i1,i2,i3

    print *,"Enter input 1"
    read  *, i1
    print *,"Enter input 1"
    read  *, i2
    print *,"Enter input 1"
    read  *, i3

    print *, "you have entered", i1, i2, i3
end program main
```

I want to write a batch file that will automatically enter the three values and then hold the screen for output but also the opportunity for the user to enter additional commands. This is what I have come up with so far in the batch file:

```
D:
cd D:\TEMP\TEST\TEST\Debug
(echo 1 
echo 2 
echo 3) | test
pause>nul
```

Unfortunately this outputs the following:
[image]

This is close to what I am looking for but it has some issues:

- the echo commands are output into the screen which I don't want to happen
- Pressing any key after the end of the batch file run will quit the command window. I want to provide the opportunity for the user to keep entering commands.

Please let me know what is a clean solution for this simple problem.

Comment: Either put `@echo off` into the first line of your script, or precede every command with `@`, also for the parenthesised block (`@( ... )`)...

Comment: true. That solves the first problem. How about the other two?

Comment: sorry yes I just caught that. I removed it from the issue list I just had typed in "Enter input 1" 3 times. My bad. Problem 3 persists however (opportunity for user to keep entering commands)

Comment: The actual question has nothing to do with fortran, it seems you want to pipe some vals to stdin and then switch to console input. My guess the solution will be such a kludge that you will be far better off to make the code read the first three vals as command line arguments.

Comment: You could combine `CHOICE /N /C RQ  /M "Press R (Repeat) or Q (Quit) "`  with `IF errorlevel 2 (goto :eof) else goto :repeat` placing the `:repeat` label somewhere before the `(echo  1` line. Read `if /?`, `goto /?` and `choice /?` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If the Fortran program will read from stdin, why not just create a temporary file with the input values and redirect it into the Fortran program?

```
CD /D D:\TEMP\TEST\TEST\Debug
SET "TEMP_FILE=%TEMP%\fortran_program_%RANDOM%.tmp"
IF EXIST "%TEMP_FILE%" (DEL "%TEMP_FILE%")
ECHO>>"%TEMP_FILE%" 1
ECHO>>"%TEMP_FILE%" 2
ECHO>>"%TEMP_FILE%" 3
test <"%TEMP_FILE%"
IF EXIST "%TEMP_FILE%" (DEL "%TEMP_FILE%")
pause>nul
```